# My jquery code is not applying to the last div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am dynamically creating divs, where I'm replacing some text with the follow code:

```
$('p.project-category').each(function()
{
    if($(this).text()==='Conferences --Events')
    {
        $('p.project-category').text('Conferences --Events').replaceWith('<p class="project-category">Conferences / Events</p>')
    }  
    else if ($(this).text()==='Html Emails')
    {
        $('p.project-category').text('Html Emails').replaceWith('<p class="project-category">HTML E-Mails</p>')
    }
    else if ($(this).text()==='Periodicals Reports')
    {
        $('p.project-category').text('Conferences Events').replaceWith('<p class="project-category">Periodicals / Reports</p>')
    }   
    else if ($(this).text()==='Sales Collateral---standard')
    {
        $('p.project-category').text('Sales Collateral---standard').replaceWith('<p class="project-category">Sales Collateral (Standard)</p>')
    }
    else if ($(this).text()==='Sites Apps')
    {
        $('p.project-category').text('Sites Apps').replaceWith('<p class="project-category">Web Sites / Digital Apps</p>')
    }
});
```

This is working for all except the last div. Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

Comment: You set one element's `text` and then replace it with another element?

Comment: Have you ever heard about `switch` ??

Comment: The reason is that the last condition condition has not been met.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `.text()` as a `selector`. If so, you're wrong.

Comment: looking @nd_macias comment, if you run the code in the if block in the console does it work? if so then they are 100% on the money.

Comment: are not all those `.text('Conferences --Events').`, `.text('Html Emails').`, etc.. bits useless? You are basically writing in the same content ... and then you replace it.

Comment: I bet you have a typo in 'Site Apps' on your html element, or an extra space.

Comment: Thank you, those who actually were helpful. I'm still learning practical javascript (versus what school teaches you)

Comment: The purpose of this is to replace parsed XML information created in Excel, for those who think this is pointless.

Comment: I believe that's what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/wdefxnjz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You have a way too messy `if .. then .. else` conditional there. You can make it more clear by using a `switch .. case` instead.

Also, it looks like you're trying to use the `.text()` method as a selector, which is wrong. It's used to `set/get` the text from the selected element.

Finally, you're replacing the whole element when you could just replace its text.

```
$('p.project-category').each(function (el, ix) {
    var text = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    var newText = '';

    switch (text) {
        case 'conferences --events':
            newText = 'Conferences / Events';
            break;

        case 'html emails':
            newText = 'HTML E-Mails';
            break;

        case 'periodicals reports':
            newText = 'Periodicals / Report';
            break;


        case 'sales collateral---standard':
            newText = 'Sales Collateral (Standard)';
            break;

        case 'sites apps':
            newText = 'Web Sites / Digital Apps';
            break;

    }

    $(this).text(newText);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/wdefxnjz/1/)

**Note** I'm assuming there are no misspellings in your `HTML` markup, and I wouldn't recommend that you rely your code on text content when making comparisons.

Comment: First: I tried this early on in the project. My current code is the only thing working on for this project, hence the spaghetti code. Secondly: This actually had the same problem, so I'm assuming that there's something in the XML. At least I know it isn't my code now, so thanks anyways.